# What to do when system stops interacting with I/O devices?

Tags: freeze, magic-sysrq

Due to some applications misbehaving (which I have to force kill), there seem to be some secondary effects on my system.

The screen output freezes, but the system stays responsive (I can ssh into the machine, and verify that no program is hogging CPU / memory).

It gives the appearance of being "frozen" though, because moving the mouse or keyboard doesn't do *anything*. The keyboard's caps lock key doesn't lead to caps light toggling.

Plugging the devices in / out doesn't help. However, the `reisub` sequence works to reboot the system, so perhaps the system doesn't stop receiving input, only the output.

I'm mostly having trouble understanding where the issue could be. But I'm in a fortunate situation of being able to ssh into the machine and have full control over it, so I'd like to know what I should try next time this happens.

System-specific details: Ubuntu 20.04 with default GNOME and X11.

Comment: Anything interesting in `dmesg`? Absolutely must be

Comment: What is your system? For example, on my Slackware, `telinit 3` logging back in and `telinit 5` does the trick most of the times.

Comment: @LjmDullaart edited the question to include more system details

Comment: in that case, it is something like `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` in stead of `telinit 3` and switch back again, probably doing something comparable, but I leave it to the `systemd` proponents to give you a definitive solution